# Managed form as child of unmanaged HWND

Tags: c#, winforms, unmanaged, hwnd

I need to show my System.Windows.Forms.Form as a child window of an unmanaged C++ HWND. This is the C# SDK code that retrieves the NativeWindow:

```
public static NativeWindow MainWindow()
{
  Diagnostics.Process process = Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
  if (null == process)
    return null;
  IntPtr handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
  if (IntPtr.Zero == handle)
    return null;

  NativeWindow wnd = new NativeWindow();
  wnd.AssignHandle(handle);

  return wnd;
}
```

This is how it is implemented in the plug-in:

```
IWin32Window rh_wnd = Rhino.RhinoApp.MainWindow();
DocEditor.Show(rh_wnd);
```

This works.... most of the time. But it also fails often the first time I call this code:

[HWND Error http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f29bc27823.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f29bc27823.png)

Call it again, everything works fine.
What's going on?!?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly because rh_wnd is null? There are atleast 2 cases where you would return null from MainWindow(). Might be a good idea to check

```
IWin32Window rh_wnd = Rhino.RhinoApp.MainWindow();
if ( rh_wnd != null )
   DocEditor.Show(rh_wnd);
```

And if the above stops the errors, you might want to check which of the above conditions returns null, and go from there.

Hope this helps.